# Swift ViewModel implementation with Array

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

Is this piece of code a correct implementation of the MVVM architecture? I'm wondering if I can keep the downloaded array in a private property for future use in a TableView, or should I avoid such situations at all costs?

The code:

```
import Foundation

class StopsViewModel {

    weak var delegate: StopsViewModelDelegate?
    private let dbService: DatabaseService
    private var stops = [Stop]()

    init(withDbService dbService: DatabaseService) {
        self.dbService = dbService
    }

    func loadStops() {
        dbService.getStops(completion: { [weak self] stops in
            self?.stops = stops
            self?.delegate?.getStopsCallFinished()
        })
    }

    func getStop(atIndex index: Int) -> Stop {
        return self.stops[index]
    }

    func getRowCount() -> Int {
        return self.stops.count
    }

    func getSectionsCount() -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}

protocol StopsViewModelDelegate: class {
    func getStopsCallFinished()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with some senior developers at work, they told me that this is the way they usually go. Since keeping the array inside the view-model doesn't break the MVVM pattern, makes it really easy to reuse the data and clears the dataservice from keeping additional fields (making it more reusable).

Comment: I was also looking for the answer. An interesting point IMO is that you have to call getStop(atIndex:) from the ViewController. Does that break MVVM pattern? since the VC has to know about the model (Stop in this case).
Is it better to have a function getStopParameter(atIndex:) -> Any? and return self.stops[index].parameter instead?